# Provisioning profiles not listed in visual studioo

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have developed a cross platform app with xamarin forms , after I completed development i went on to testing . I successfully deployed to an andriod device and all is good on that platform, but im struggling to deploy the app to my physical iphone iv have searched EVERYWHERE and couldn’t find any help, this is my situation:

I have created free provisioning profiles and all the necessary certification according to the Microsoft guide on free provisioning

I successfully deployed a dummy app to my physical device throught xcode(so that means provisiong was successfull ????)

But my signing ID and provisioning profile is not listed in visual studio 2019
And yes

I did pair to my mac and connected my iphone to the mac AND targeted my iphone in the build scheme

Bundle ID’s also match and my iphone is visible in VS but i my profile is not listed so i cant deploy.
And yes my apple ID is also added under tools > xamarin > apple id

Ive also tried restarting the IDE and my machine Multiple times

PLEASE PLEAAASEE help me

Comment: Did you use Xamarin Essentials SecureStorage in your development?

Answer (score 1):

Create new project with your XCode.

Make sure you set the correct Bundle ID.

**Try to build your XCode project (for debug and release), if anything work re-start your VS and you will see your provisioning profile.**

Comment: What do you mean by “correct bundle id” should n create an entirely new signing identity and provisioning profile ? I need a more detail

Comment: I have reached my max limit for signing ID’s

Comment: I just tried to run the app without selecting siging ids in xamarin.ios bundle signing

Comment: @Kyle Now you have solution about your problem?

Comment: Yes i came right but i cant tell you what i did i dont know why it suddenly worked, suggest to not try free provisioning and just  buy the apple dev program